# Changing the scoring mechanism in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a few documents in Elastic Search and a field name "text". I want to search for a list of tokens with custom scoring mechanism. The score should be (number_of_tokens_matched / total_number_of_tokens).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: how you want to retrieve list of tokens? in es you will get back a list of documents

Comment: The list of tokens will be used provided. I want to search for these tokens in a particular field of my data.

Comment: please show an example than, pseudocode or something